# Windows Phone - Serialization for tombstoning

Tags: serialization, windows-phone-8, datacontractserializer, tombstoning

I'm looking for a Serializer for Windows Phone 8. The DataContractSerializer doesn't work for me because the data members needs to be public and they need public setters.

I don't need a huge library for tombstoning, I think a smart serializer would fit for me. It would be nice if the serializer returns a serialization-string that can be stored into PhoneApplicationPage.State because i Dont't want to use the IsolatedStorage.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could use [Json.net which you can install with nuget.](http://nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/)

Not sure if that works for you though, when DataContractSerializer doesn't.
Serialize example:

`String result = await JsonConvert.SerializeObjectAsync(yourobject);`

or

`String result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourobject);`

and deserialize example:

`T _data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(yourstringobject);`

Comment: Is it possible to store the Type of serialization object into the JSON, because I have different object types and do not know it at runtime.

Comment: @websocialist I don't know, sorry

Comment: Is there support for binary format, because I have a byte array field and need to serialize them too?